# warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)(int *, int *, int)’

Tags: c

So I'm new to SO and my question was not well recived...so I edited it to be more informative.

I'm trying to write a program that calls two functions in the main program. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int inner_product(int a[], int b[], int n);
int inner_product_reverse(int a[], int b[], int n);

int main(void) {
int a[N], b[N], i;

printf("Enter the first array of size 10: ");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);

printf("Enter the second array of size 10: ");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    scanf("%d", &b[i]);

printf("Inner product is: %d\n", inner_product);
printf("Inner product reverse is: %d\n", inner_product_reverse);
return 0;
}

int inner_product(int a[], int b[], int n) {
int sum = 0, i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    sum += (a[i] * b[i]);
return sum;
}

int inner_product_reverse(int a[], int b[], int n) {
int sum = 0, i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    sum += (a[i] * b[(N-1)-i]);
return sum;
```

But I get the error in the title. I know that it's an issue of the difference in number of arguments called but I'm not sure how to write it in a way that will take into account all of the arguments of the functions. 
Would I have to move the for loop that computes the inner product into the main somehow? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter? Show your efforts. SO is not a service for doing your homework.

Comment: Define best. A simple for-loop would get the job done.

Comment: If you call a function which is returning int variable, then call the function, don't pass the pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in calling `printf` function as the warning already said.

```
printf("Inner product is: %d\n", inner_product);
printf("Inner product reverse is: %d\n", inner_product_reverse);
```

`inner_product` and `inner_product_reverse` are functions which return int and accepts 3 parameters: `int (*)(int *, int *, int)`.

Now to get int result, call these 2 functions. What you did is that you passed pointer (location) of them to printf function and this is wrong.

You should rewrite your code to something similar to:

```
//                               Parameters are added and function will be called
printf("Inner product is: %d\n", inner_product(a, b, i));
printf("Inner product reverse is: %d\n", inner_product_reverse(a, b, i));
```